# Kotlin inferred type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to setup JobService using FirebaseJobDispatcher.

Here is my JobService:

```
class MyJobService : JobService() {
override fun onStartJob(job: JobParameters): Boolean {
    // Do some work here
   return false //return false if job done otherwise return true
}

override fun onStopJob(job: JobParameters): Boolean {
    return false //Should this job be retried?"
   }
}
```

However when i try to setup it like this:

```
val dispatcher = FirebaseJobDispatcher(GooglePlayDriver(this))
val myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(MyJobService::class.java) // the JobService that will be called
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")        // uniquely identifies the job
    .build()
```

I am getting this compiler error in Android Studio:

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class but Class! was expected

How to setup it in Kotlin correctly?

Comment: You should try to `.setService(MyJobService::class)` or `.setService(MyJobService::class.java!!)` (to be compliant with Class!) I guess.

Comment: I've tried both before - not worked

Comment: Are you using the latest version ? `firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'` ? I'm seeing `Improve Kotlin support (#193)` in their repository. Your code seems to be correct based on what I've read.

Comment: Yes, I am using exactly that version. I've created an issue also: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/231

Comment: Hey I am facing same issue ! any updates on this ?

Comment: @UmarFarooque check my answer

Comment: doesn't help i still get the same error and also those imports are not being used in my case..., Error:(79, 49) Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class<MyJobService> but Class<out JobService!>! was expected

Comment: In my case with exact same code as above everything is working, maybe you can check it and compare again with my?

Comment: My bad.. it worked after cleaning.. thanks man !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I imported wrong JobService.

Instead of:

```
import android.app.job.JobParameters
import android.app.job.JobService
```

Should be:

```
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService
```